# Refresh button in Visual Studio Solution Explorer not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, solution-explorer

Just got Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop and finding myself overly annoyed that the Solution Explorer doesn't accurately reflect the state of my project. I keep clicking Refresh, but it doesn't actually do anything. [Microsoft's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f1w05k2y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) rather, uh, verbose explanation of how to use it was no help. Oddly enough, my project does refresh sometimes, but I can't figure out what the cause is. It's definitely not the refresh button.

Here's what my Solution Explorer looks like right now:
[image: my solution explorer]
I've deleted a lot of these classes. Things like "Term" are what I typed while in the process of naming a class, but the Solution Explorer shows them as separate classes. Also some of the classes I have aren't showing up.

This whole thing is really messed up, and I'm having trouble visualizing what my project looks like because Solution Explorer doesn't show an up-to-date outline of my classes.

**How do I refresh the Solution Explorer?**

Comment: What state is it not reflecting? Do you want to click Show All Files?

Answer (score 81):

There's a "show all files" button in the top row of Solution Explorer. Click that and you should see your missing files/folders. Right click and choose "Include in Project".

[image: show all files]

Comment: It's not the files that are missing. It's the classes in a single file that are messed up.

Comment: I have a similar problem I think. I reverted a file from Git, but don't see how to refresh that file in VS (2010)

Comment: My answer above didn't work? Clicking "Show All Files", then right click -> "Include in Project"?

Comment: For class details, such as the declaration order of members, toggling Show All Files twice seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 15):

Choose the project where you deleted the file and than click on show all files [image]

Now you will get excluded/Removed files
[image]

Right Click > include in project.

Comment: Sure it does. http://imgur.com/a/z2K2C. Make sure the PROJECT is selected from the top level. It works at the project level, not the entire solution.

Comment: Hello, I think you should remove this answer - since it is the *same* as the previously posted and higher-upvoted answer by dmathisen below.

Answer (score 5):

There is a refresh icon option in the top row of solution explorer.
[image: check the image]

Comment: That option has been removed in VS2017

Comment: As of 2018 it's there but doesn't refresh as expected.

Comment: Why was it removed in 2017? It has gone from mine too, but is essential for gulp, etc.

Comment: Refresh button exists in VS2017, but it is shown when a project or project items are selected - not when a solution or solution folders are selected. It also helps when there is a yellow warning mark on referenced assemblies (also cleaning ReSharper's cache in this case).

Comment: There is no Refresh button on DotNetCore projects I've recently created. Drives me batshit crazy (doesn't matter WHAT you click on before - project, file, folder - NADA - no refresh!).  I can create a brand new Core 2.1 project template and, apparently, it is not supported. There must be some secret, hidden, setting that isn't documented solely to drive developers insane - and requires editing an obscure setting buried in a file.  (sarcasm)

Answer (score 0):

I had my project running, and nothing was refreshing. Stopping my project returned fresh files/folders.